# WSO2 AS guice integration

Tags: wso2, apache-axis, guice-servlet

I am using WSO2 application server to deploy my web services. I would like to use guice in my project. I have read a maksim [blog](http://maksim.sorokin.dk/it/2011/02/23/axis2-guice-maven-servlets/) about axis2 guice integration. He has used web.xml for injection however i do not know how could i change web.xml in wso2 as.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You didn't want to change web.xml on WSO2 AS. You can have web.xml on your WS project.

here is complete guide on developing WS and how to deploy on WSO2 AS using WSO2 Developer Studio.

http://wso2.com/library/articles/2012/09/develop-deploy-web-applications-using-wso2-developer-studio/

Using WSO2 DS you can ease your development effort.

Answer (score 0):

There is no much difference. You implement your webservice/webapp. Web.xml is the part of your webapp . Create the war file and deploy that in AS. Keep the dependency jars(guice lib etc ..) in the repository/components/lib folder.